# View entire file's path in Traktor when path is long

Tags: windows-7, traktor

I would like to view the entire path of a track in Traktor. Is there any way to do so when the path is long? Usually I right click on the track, then select "edit" in the contextual menu, then scroll down and I have the path, long paths are chopped:

[image]

How can I view the entire file's path in Traktor when the path is long?

I use [Traktor Pro 2.6.5](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/dj-software/traktor-pro-2/specifications/) on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Traktor has many annoying little bugs like this, the only way to achieve this is to display it as a column in the playlist. To do this right click on the column headers of the playlist and click `File`. You'll now have a new column called File which can be expended to see the full path.